# Filling database laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I can fill my table with User::create(). It works, but I want fill with class, which I create in migrations. How I can do it? I am beginner at php laravel and can`t find information on this case.
web.php:

```
<?php
Route::name('user.')->group(function (){
    Route::view('/private','private')->middleware('auth')->name('private');
    Route::get('/login',function(){
//        Проверка на авторизацию пользователя. Если уже авторизован, то редирект на страницу профиля
        return view('login');
    })->name('login');
    Route::post('/login',[\App\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class,'login']);
    Route::get('/logout',function(){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    })->name('logout');
    Route::get('/registration', function () {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }
        return view('registration');
    })->name('registration');
    Route::post('/registration',[\App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController::class,'save']);
});
```

registration.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Регистрация
@endsection
@section('content')
    <h1>Вход</h1>
    <form class="col-3 offset-4 border rounded" method="POST" action="{{route('user.registration')}}">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number" class="col-form-label-lg">Имя</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="number" name="number" type="text"  placeholder="number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="surname" class="col-form-label-lg">surname</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" type="text"  placeholder="surname">
       </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="col-form-label-lg">Имя</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Имя">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-form-label-lg">Пароль</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" type="password"  placeholder="Пароль">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="sendMe" value="1">Войти</button>
        </div>


    </form>
@endsection
```

RegisterController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function save(Request $request){
        if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('user.private'));
        }

    $validateFields = $request->validate([

        'number' =>'required',
        'password' => 'required',

    ]);
        if(User::where('number',$request['number'])->exists()){
            return redirect(route('user.registration'))->withErrors([
                'number' => 'Такой пользователь уже зарегистрирован'
            ]);
        }
    $user = User::create([

        'password' => $request['password'],
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'surname'=>$request['surname'],
        'number'=>$request['number']
    ]);

    if($user){
        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect(route('user.private'));
    }
        return redirect(route('user.login'))->withErrors([
            'formError' => 'Произошла ошибка при сохранении пользователя'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Migration file. This file creates the users schema. With this class I want to save users
create_users_table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('users',function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('surname',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('name',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('number',255)->nullable(false)->unique();
            $table->string('father`s name',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('parent`s number',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('password',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('studies',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('classes',255)->nullable(false);
            $table->string('remember_token',100)->nullable(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're after, is [Seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding) what you're looking for?

Comment: Column names like `father\`s name` or `parent\`s number` _might_ give you trouble later on

Comment: I have to delete space between names?

Comment: I also don't understand your question. Try to improve it.

Comment: Are you asking about seeding the users table with rows? Exampe docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/seeding